# How to enable CORS in AppRTC?

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine, go, apprtc

I have deployed my own apprtc server with collider & turn server configured in Google App engine locally with virtualbox. Everything is working properly but I want to use this apprtc server in my another project that is in anoter IP. So, Apprtc IP and my project IP is different. Now, when I included `apprtc.debug.js` & `appwindow.js` files to my project it cannot initialize loadingParams and says this error message "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `http://<IP OF APPRTC>:8080/params`. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)".

However, entering `http://<IP OF APPRTC>:8080/params` in the browser gives me correct response but not in the project called in appwindow.js .After a bit of googling I added below lines in sendUrlRequest function :

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

Now it says "CORS request did not succeed". 
How can I make it work? Do I have to enable cors in server side also, if so where and how to do that? Please help me, I'm totally lost here...

Comment: It's not clear from the description if you are running if you are running TURN server locally or in Google App Engine. Could you clarify that?

Comment: Also for cors please review this section about headers in [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_http_headers)